# BUILD FAILED when I want to get SHA1 ran gradlew signingReport

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

apple@Apples-MacBook-Pro android % ./gradlew signingReport

Welcome to Gradle 7.6!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Added support for Java 19.
- Introduced `--rerun` flag for individual task rerun.
- Improved dependency block for test suites to be strongly typed.
- Added a pluggable system for Java toolchains provisioning.

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/apple/Karthik/Hecho eshop/eShop MultiVendor Projecr V2.6.0/Seller Flutter Project V2.6.0/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/7.6/scripts/dv46f4cmrgq0n1uvu9oootzoj).

\> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:

\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

\> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

apple@Apples-MacBook-Pro android %

how to solve this error